# Hibernate Java: Function "AES_DECRYPT" not found; SQL statement:

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

My MySQL Version: 5.6.25

Encountered a problem when querying to database.

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "AES_DECRYPT" not found; SQL statement:

Model:

```
@Column(nullable = false)
    @ColumnTransformer(
            read="AES_DECRYPT(title, SHA2('" + AESConfig.SECRET_KEY + "',512))", 
            write="AES_ENCRYPT(?,SHA2('" + AESConfig.SECRET_KEY + "',512))")
    private String title;
```

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

You should register AES_DECRYPT function to use it in hql queries.

Try to use something like this:

```
registerFunction("aes_encrypt", new StandardSQLFunction("aes_encrypt", Hibernate.STRING) )
registerFunction("aes_decrypt", new StandardSQLFunction("aes_decrypt", Hibernate.STRING) )
```

You should extend standard MySqlDialect class

```
MyCustomDialect extends MySQLDialect {

  public MyCustomDialect () {
    super();
    registerFunction("MyFunction", ....); // Second argument is an implementation of SQLFunction interface
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am new to hibernate. Where can I put that code?

Comment: @kenicky Create your own Dialecte class.

Comment: is this dialect valid? org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

Comment: how can I use that class?